# Ember left nav creation

Tags: ember.js

I need to create a left nav in ember that functions very much like the left nav on the [ember website](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/).  I am currently on Ember 1.X which has poor serialization support for nested JSON.  I started off with this data model which I do not believe will work with Ember 1.X:

```
var menuItems = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Payroll',
  children: { 
        'Child 1',
        'Child 2'
    }
  },{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Time & Attendance',
    children: { 
        'Child 1',
        'Child 2',
        'child 3'
    }
}];
```

When I build this model I get a syntax error:

`Unexpected token`

```
title: 'Payroll',
children: {
          'Child 1', //There's an arrow pointing to the ',' here
          'Child 2'
},{
```

Why do I get this error?

I have my menu `template.js` built like this (*untested):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="navMenu nav list-unstyled">
          {{#each model as |menuItem|}}
            {{#if isActive}}
              <span {{action "makeInactive"}} class="">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
              <ul>
                {{#each child as |children|}}
                  <li><a href="#">{{child}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
              </ul>
            {{else}}
              <span {{action "makeActive"}} class="">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
            {{/if}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">Will be content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will sort of work, but I'll need some way to ensure only 1 element is active at a time.

Do I need to update to ember 2.X to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need ember 2 for this. I would suggest either adding 'selected' property to your model or else use [Ember.ProxyObject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectProxy.html) to add an extra property called 'selected' on each of you menuItem object so we can capture which one is in active state, and then do following:

Your template would look like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="navMenu nav list-unstyled">
          {{#each menuItems as |menuItem|}}
              <span {{action "toggleActive" menuItem}} class="">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
               {{#if menuItem.selected}}
                  <ul>
                    {{#each menuItem.children as |child|}}
                      <li><a href="#">{{child}}</a></li>
                    {{/each}}
                  </ul>
               {{/if}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">Will be content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your controller would look like:

```
menuItems : Ember.computed.map('model', function(menuItem, index) {
    if(menuItem.get('childItems.length')){
        return Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
           content: menuItem,
           selected: false
        });
    }
}),

actions:{
    toggleActive: function(menuProxy){
       this.get('menuItemsProxy').setEach('selected', false);
       menuProxy.set('selected', true);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Lot has changed in ember data but give this a try:

```
//assuming you are using ember cli
export default Ember.Model.create({
    title:DS.attr('string'),
    childItems: DS.hasMany('menuItem', {async: true})
});
```

and your JSON response for menuItem api should be:

```
{
    "menuItems": [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Payroll',
            childItems: [3, 4]

        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Time & Attendance',
            children: [5, 6]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'child of payroll',
            childItems: []
        },...
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is helpful in a lot of ways.  I updated the question because my model is giving me a syntax error.  I thought this error was due to Ember 1.X being unable to handle a nested model as I defined.  I have to get past this error to try this.  I should have mentioned this in the original question.

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe it will help - since I have not played with ember data for quite a bit.